# Rails Migrate Active Storage from Image Magick to Libvips without regenerating images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

We have a Rails 7 system with roughly 50,000 photos stored in Active Storage that we transform to different sizes using `variant`. Currently, we use Image Magick as the backend for image_processing and we would like to change to libvips, which is also the default in more recent rails versions (see for example [this](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/make-vips-the-recommended-default-variant-processor-for-active-storage/78368))

Unfortunately, the options hash passed to `variant` needs to be changed for libvips in our application. For example: (and a lot more examples [here](https://gist.github.com/brenogazzola/a4369965a1da426d50f11d080fe2e563))

```
variant(format: :jpg, strip: true, quality: 80) # imagemagick
variant(format: :jpg, saver: { strip: true, quality: 80 }) # libvips / image_processing
```

Rails uses this hash internally to uniquely identify the variant. Thus, if we change our variant descriptions to fit libvips, this would cause Rails to regenerate 100,000's of images if not even more, which we would obviously like to avoid.

Is there any standard solution to this problem?

One option I was considering is to first test if the imagemagick variant already exists and if so use that, like so:

```
def create_variant
  magick_variant = image.variant(format: :jpg, strip: true, quality: 80)
  return magick_variant.processed.url if magick_variant.processed?
  
  image.variant(format: :jpg, saver: { strip: true, quality: 80 }).processed.url
end
```

Sadly, `VariantWithRecord#processed?` [has been made private](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c18bcd582819212c0d8d5523f7918cd4c1c4d53f#diff-62446911aa1816b5e62122626b466e5064e326475dc1a348d6174b334aea31d1R32) in Rails 7.1 and isn't a sustainable solution therefore.

Answer (score 0):

We did the migration by collecting the bigger part (around 80%) of the variant transformations we use, calculating their digests before the migration and after the migration and then manually updating the digests stored in `active_storage_variant_records`.

For example:

```sql
UPDATE `active_storage_variant_records` 
SET `variation_digest` = CASE `variation_digest`
   WHEN '8HYTSoAKrOz5PQZaB5rF21hDWks=' THEN 'ols+mvCHaSFFmjPwGcc9zwr6A6Y='
   WHEN 'LzJ443LpJ9ZNnqCVgpoG3j43nC0=' THEN 'Safska55MupNqvs4kO2JOJxLNoU='
END
WHERE `active_storage_variant_records`.`variation_digest` 
IN ('8HYTSoAKrOz5PQZaB5rF21hDWks=', 'LzJ443LpJ9ZNnqCVgpoG3j43nC0=');
```

This works because `VariantRecord` uses `has_one_attached` again and the key under which the variant blob is stored is independent from the digest.